# Taxonomy thumbnails in views

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, theming

This is something I have run across on multiple drupal sites so I feel like

A) There MUST be a straight forward way to do this as there usually is with drupal

B) this must have already been answered (I just can't find a suitable answer when searching)

C) If there's a module that does this that I'm unaware of, that's a fine solution.

When using contextual filters with taxonomy I often want "no results" to give a summary. But a linked list of terms is pretty unattractive. What I want is to add thumbnails and lay it out (often in a grid). Taking the first thumbnail from the term is ok, though setting the image would be even better.

Take a look here: http://worldtouringentertainment.sander-martijn.com/categories - once you click on a category you get thumbnails of the primary/featured image and can click through to the actual content page - but this page is just a list of links.

Is it possible, without creating a totally separate view or a static page (both of which require further long-term management for non-savvy clients), to get a thumbnail into this first list so it looks attractive?

Comment: if the link above doesn't work by the time you try to answer, it will soon be http://worldtouringentertainment.com/categories - another example (which in this case worked fine without thumbnails, just another example of using taxonomy summary) is http://jessicacastellano.com/

Comment: I haven't time for a proper answer but there are theme templates you can override to change the output of the summary. See views-view-summary.tpl.php and views-view-summary-unformatted.tpl.php. Google "themeing views" for info on how to find out what template you need to override and how to override it.